# Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference - How do I change properly the value of a TextView

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, textview

I know where my problem exactly is, I just don't know how to fix it. I'm trying to change the value of a TextView and with my code, the app just crashes and I get the error in the title.

My code:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if(authenticate() == true) {
        displayUserDetails();
    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class));
    }
}

private boolean authenticate() {
    return userLocalStore.getUserStatus();
}

private void displayUserDetails() {
    User user = userLocalStore.getLoggedInUser();

    final TextView userName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userName);
    userName.setText(user.name);
    final TextView userEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userEmail);
    userEmail.setText(user.email);
}
```

There you have a snippet of my code, if you need the whole class I'd be happy to provide. Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:**

The issue was the content view as it was set to activity_main and since i couldn't switch to another I just did this:

```
private void displayUserDetails() {
    User user = userLocalStore.getLoggedInUser();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    View header=navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

    final TextView userName = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.userName);
    userName.setText(user.name);
    final TextView userEmail = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.userEmail);
    userEmail.setText(user.email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be the problem that when the function is invoked initially user.email value remains empty.

Comment: Nah, I tried the other way as well, getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct, the problem is that `findViewById()` returns null.

There could be a lot of causes of the problem.

1. Check that your .xml file have views with id userName and userName.
2. Check that this .xml is accessible by all devices, i.e. it is present in all layout folders, for all screen sizes, densities, languages and so on.
3. Try to comment out one of the `.setText()`'s and see if other one is working. If it is just make sure that not working one is exactly the same.
4. If you are using an activity make sure that you call `.setContentView()` with correct layout file.
5. If you are using a fragment make sure that you return a view constructed put of a correct layout file from `onCreateView`.

Comment: I fixed it, check my update. (Upvote please, I found too many people struggling with this one and trying to find the answer in a different direction)